# I'm trying to load a custom layout, it loads the layout but not the module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I was looking at a few answers here but just one did it. (Load a custom layout in a module).

I've tried with:

```
$this->layout('layout/something');
```

But it didn't worked then i saw it:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTemplate('layout/something');

return $viewModel;
```

I have this in the module config:

```
'template_map' => array(
     'layout/something'=> __DIR__.'/../view/layout/something_layout.twig',
),
```

Then when i browse this, it prints the template layout but not the module's view.

Any help?

UPDATE:
 I've found the error. This is because i've installed ZfcTwig and this module basically ignores the layouts of ZF2, i have to extend (in the view file) to the layout that i'm going to use. But the problem of it is that this ignores the ZF2 layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Layout` controller plugin to switch layout:

```
// A controller's action method that uses an alternative
// layout template.
public function indexAction() {
  //...

  // Use the Layout plugin to access the ViewModel
  // object associated with layout template.
  $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/layout2');

  //...
}
```

Comment: Hey! thanks by answer. I've found the error. This is because i've installed ZfcTwig and this module basically ignores the layouts of ZF2, i have to extend (in the view file) to the layout that i'm going to use. But the problem of it is that this ignores the ZF2 layouts. Also, again. Thanks!